# Spring boot: Upload several MultipartFile with several additional data

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to create an endpoint that:

1. Receives N `ItemType`.
2. Receive 1 `GroupType`.

Each `ItemType` has:

1. attributes.
2. `MultipartFile`.

`GroupType` only contains attributes.

```
public class ItemType {
  private String description;
  private String security;
  private Date bestdate;
  private MultipartFile content;
}

public class GroupType {
  private String description;
  private String security;
  private String metadata;
}
```

So, my endpoint would be something like:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> group(
    List<ItemType> items,
    GroupType group);
```

I don't know if it's the best approach. Some thinks comes up with this approach:

1. What about `GroupType.security` and `ItemType.security`?
2. What about `MultiPart` files?

How might this endpoint be called?

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not a good idea to send all the data along with files in one go. The request will be too big to handle and can get timed out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Multipart-FormData.

Enabling multipart properties:

```
# MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true # Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB # Max file 
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB # Max Request Size
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadWithData(
        @RequestPart("itemTypes") List<ItemType> ,
        @RequestPart("group") Group group
        @RequestPart MultipartFile[] file) {
    // your code
}
```

`ItemType` will contain ***filename*** field to allow linking of ItemType to the uploaded file.

Comment: What does `@RequestPart("itemTypes")` means? How could I make a request using postman?

Comment: @Jordi In multpart-form-data, the request data is separated by boundaries. Besides encoded data, an identifier is used for the data. "itemTypes" is that identifier. It is identifying the part of the request data which contains the list of items. Reference: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/ I hope this is helpful. feel free to ask questions.